# Cosmos db OFFSET LIMIT clause is not working

Tags: c#, azure

```
SELECT * FROM C OFFSET 4 LIMIT 2
```

This query should return two rows, instead it returns 6. Similarly, if OFFSET 6 AND TAKE 4, it returns 10 rows

This is a brand new implementation from Microsoft team in cosmos db

```
SELECT * FROM C OFFSET 4 LIMIT 2 


SELECT * FROM C OFFSET 4 LIMIT 2
```

This query should return two rows, instead it returns 6. Similarly, if OFFSET 6 AND TAKE 4, it returns 10 rows

Comment: i ran the query in cosmosdb playground it looks fine

Comment: can you please post your code example here

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to use Query Explorer on Azure portal. This blade will be retired soon. Please use Data Explorer going forward.

I can reproduce your issue if I use Query Explorer. The Data Explorer works well.
[image]