# How to execute pagenation by specifying the number of items per page for the query result of Cosmos DB?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm planning to develop an application that executes a query against Cosmos DB with Azure Functions (Http Trigger), returns the query result as a response, and displays the response on the WEB-UI.

I'm trying to page the query results because a long query result can exceed the Azure LB timeout default (230 seconds).

In the case of paging with a continuation token, paging will occur before the query result reaches maxItemCount, such as when the response size exceeds the upper limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits

The method of specifying OFFSET and LIMMIT in RDB SQL is deprecated by Micosoft, and it has been reported that it does not work properly.

[Cosmos db OFFSET LIMIT clause is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099781/cosmos-db-offset-limit-clause-is-not-working)

How to execute pagenation by specifying the number of items per page for the query result of Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
CosmosQueryRequestOptions queryOptions = new CosmosQueryRequestOptions();

Iterable<FeedResponse<Family>> feedResponseIterator =
                    container.queryItems(query, queryOptions, Family.class).iterableByPage(continuationToken,pageSize);
```

More details, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/main/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/queries/sync/QueriesQuickstart.java#L216-L266).

Comment: how to write Junit for this code? how can we create a real dummy instance of CosmosPagedIterable?